# Pygame detecting collisions between pictures

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I am quite new to programming, and recently I decided to start Pygame. Based on a tutorial I found, I created this game. The aim is to watch the ball bounce around and keep it away from the box at the bottom by clicking at the right time. I know the code is a bit messy, but the big problem is although the code runs, the game doesn't quit as it should when the ball and the box touch.

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 320, 240
speed = [2, 2]
black = 0, 0, 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
ball = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
target = pygame.image.load("square_target.bmp")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
target_place = [160, 200]
fps = 60

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect <= target_place[0] + 50 or ballrect <= target_place[1] + 50:
        pygame.event.post(pygame.QUIT)

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    screen.blit(target, target_place)
    pygame.display.flip()
    fps += 0.01
    print (fps)
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Any help?

Comment: replace `while 1:` with `while not done:` and set `done = True` when your collision happens.

Answer (score 6):

Pygame includes a built in method to check if two rectangles overlap. Therefore, if this condition is true:

```
ballrect.colliderect(target.get_rect())
```

...it means the two images overlap.

Comment: Okay, I thought I had got it to work but now when I run the program it shows the screen for a split second then closes. I added some print things to work out what was going on and it turned out that whenever the program checked to see if the pictures overlapped it returned that they were and therefore quit. Any suggestions?